# Rewriterule - How to add .html in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How do I create a rewriterule to 301 redirect urls like this:

http://www.domain.dk/bornetoj/body/

to:

http://www.domain.dk/bornetoj/body.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Change all of your links in your content to look like this: `http://www.domain.dk/bornetoj/body/`
2. The the htaccess in your document root, add these rules to convert the links without `.html` to add it so that resources can be properly resolved, preferably above any rules you may already have:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*?)/?$
   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.html -f
   RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.html [L]
   ```
3. In case you still have links outside of your control, you can add these rules to make sure the html extension gets removed by redirecting browsers to the one without the extenion:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /(^[\ \?]+)\.html
   RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.|/$) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.html [R=301,L]
```